# Tomcat SSL Different Keystore and Key password

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have been trying to configure tomcat, however I have come across a small problem.  My keystore and key have different passwords, if I try to configure as per the below then https will not work.  If I make the passwords match it does work.  Is there anyway to tell tomcat that the key password is different? or is this a limitation?  I am using Tomcat 7 version 63

```
<Connector port="7001" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       keystoreFile="d:/path/to/Keystore.jks"  keystorePass="KeystorePassword"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Thanks

Comment: when you say it doesn't work what kind of error do you get

Comment: Ahh Ok, I have resolved this issue, as the keyStorePassword and key password were different All I had to do was add the following keyPass=<MyKeyPassword>   I feel pretty stupid now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ahh Ok, I have resolved this issue, as the keyStorePassword and key password were different All I had to do was add the following keyPass= I feel pretty stupid now!

Comment: Don't feel that stupid... I was having the same problem and didn't find any reference to the `keyPass` syntax anywere. Although I had my config working, I was worried about security concerns. Now you have resolved my doubts. Thanks a lot!